# Nautilus shortcut for creating empty files

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, nautilus

Is there any keyboard shortcut in Nautilus for creating new empty files. Like Shift-Ctrl-N does for folders. If there isn't, is there a way to add this custom shortcut somehow?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no such shortcut by default, but you may open context menu via keyboard, and then press the underlined characters one after another, e.g. <kbd>context menu key</kbd> , <kbd>d</kbd>, <kbd>u</kbd> (on my language version)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of a keyboard shortcut but if you go to `~/templates/` and create an empty file there, you will be able to create an empty file via the right-click menu.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no keyboard shortcut for adding new files, but you could create new files using the contextmenu.

1. Inside your folder, press Ctrl+F10. This keystroke displays the context menu as if you right-clicked an empty space.
2. Click New Document or press D
3. Select the new Document

If you want more documenttypes available you could add them to your `~/Templates` folder

Based on this great thread: [Need shortcut to New Document context submenu in Nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/q/1065384/1045718) and [its solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1065390/1045718)